# unable to open the app from email client in android

Tags: android, email

I am writing the application to open HTML files. In some devices (like Galaxy player,nexus one) when i try to open html file from Email client  ,my application is not showing in

> "open with"

open with " dialog ,but if i open the same HTML file from Gmail client my app is showing in

> "open with "

open with" dialog . In other devices(like Google nexus ,S2 etc), i am able to open the HTML file through my application  from Email client, Email client .is this device specific issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some devices Email client is not opening the app with mime type as text/html.so i changed like follows.

```
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
             <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Then email app is able to show my application in the list.but it will show when we tring to opne HTML/Text files.

Answer (score 0):

If your app opens .HTML files, the intent filter should look something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
  <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.html" />
  <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
  <data android:scheme="file" />
  <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Sorry.after putting the above lines ,it is not showing from Gmail also.

Comment: Try again but use `<data android:scheme="content" />`.

Comment: Actually I believe if you room `android:scheme` then both "content" and "file" are inferred, but you might just need to `intent-filter`s.

Comment: I applied <data android:scheme="content" /> then also not working

Comment: Sorry I meant "remove" not "room".